# Show other domain using DNS instead of iframe

Tags: redirects, dns, iframe

I have two domains bought at different providers and I would like `http://aaaaa.com` to show `http://bbbbb.com/aaaaa`.

Is this possible using only DNS? Must I transfer the domain to my hosting provider?
I really don't want to use a redirection or iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this could be done using some rewrite-rules.

f.e:

you could set the A records for the domains to the same server, then check what is coming in and rewite it...

see for apache:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html
there is also one for IIS
http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/

update: on shared-hosting environments .htaccess is more likely the place where  this could be set.

cu

Answer (score 0):

I think people typically use Reverse Proxies in this case. For example you can set up any request for:

```
http://a.com to serve the content from http://b.com/a.
```

You can read more about this on [Apachetutor Reverse Proxies](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies)